# use regex in a text file vb.net

Tags: regex, vb.net

I want to read specific text in this file 'config.txt'

```
action url: "item1"
referer: "item2"
post data: 'item3'
```

my code:

```
dim item1 as string
dim item2 as string
dim item3 as string

textbox1.text = (item1)
textbox2.text = (item2)
textbox3.text = (item3)
```

I want item1 to = `action url: "(*.?)" CaptureGroup(1).Value` read from the text file and so on with item2 and item3

Answer (score 0):

If the file is always this format perhaps you don't need a regex? :-

```
Dim FileContent As String = "action url: .... etc"
Dim DivArr As Char() = {Chr(34), Chr(39)}
'split into segments using single & double quotes as separators
Dim parts() As String = FileContent.Split(DivArr)

textbox1.text = parts(1)
textbox2.text = parts(3)
textbox3.text = parts(5)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

 Private Function match(regex As String, html As String, Optional i As Integer = 1) As String
        Return New Regex(regex, RegexOptions.Multiline).Match(html).Groups(i).Value.Trim()
    End Function
```

example

```
 match("action url: ""(*.?)"" CaptureGroup(1).Value", inputstring)
```